# Un-concatenated build using webpack

Tags: webpack

We are doing a black-duck scan in our company to check for Open Source license compatibility. One of the requirements of this scan is an un-minified and un-concatenated build. I know we can generate `Source-maps` using Webpack but is there a way to get an `un-concatenated` (each required file as a seperate file) build or generate an equivalent to that using the Source-maps?

I don't want to change the entire build system just for the scan. And this scan has to be done only on the shipped files which means it has to go through the same build process as our Prod-build

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the split-by-path webpack plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-split-by-path which will create one file per vendor:

`var SplitByPathPlugin = require('webpack-split-by-path');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: 'app.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: "[name]-[chunkhash].js",
    chunkFilename: "[name]-[chunkhash].js"
  },
  plugins: [
    new SplitByPathPlugin([
      {
        name: 'vendor',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
      }
    ], {
      manifest: 'app-entry'
    })
  ]
};`